# Selecting columns from two tables and summing it up

Tags: mysql, select

I have edited my question. Hope this helps....

I have two tables

**Table 1** has the following fields
ID,
Incomehead
subIncomeHead

**Table 2** has the following fields
ID,
Incomehead,
Amount

I am trying to create one SQL query in mySQL where I get all unique records (tabel1.Incomehead) from table 1 and get the sum of amount (table2.amount) from table 2 where table1.incomehead = table2.incomehead. I also need to display "0" where the table2.amount is not there for a particular table1.incomehead. The primary key in table1 is Incomehead and SubIncomehead. Therefore, there will be a scenario where the same Incomehead will be repeating as mentioned below

***Snapshot***

TABLE 1

```
1|Subscription|Membership

2|Donation|Charity

3|Collection

4|Subscription|Carpark

5|Donation|Youth
```

TABLE 2

```
1|Subscription|100

2|Donation|100

3|Subscription|500
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
Subscription|600

Donation|100

Collection|0
```

The answer below works when there is one unique record for Incomehead. However, when there are multiple records of the same value, it gives a different result

Hope this clarifies and look forward to your support

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `UNION`. Just `JOIN` the two tables and use `SUM` with  `group by`:

```
SELECT
  t1.incomehead,
  SUM(COALESCE(t2.amount, 0)) AS Total
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.incomehead = t2.incomehead
GROUP BY t1.incomehead
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

`LEFT JOIN` will include those items from the first table event if there is no matching rows form the second table, and it will have `amount` null.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/742a44/3)

This will give you:

```
|   Incomehead | Total |
|--------------|-------|
| Subscription |   600 |
|     Donation |   100 |
|   Collection |     0 |
```

---

**Side note:** You should create a foreign key between the two tables instead of using a string value to join between them, the string values for `incomehead` shouldn't be duplicated between the two tables. Instead remove it from the second table and create a new key `incomeheadID` that will be a foreign key to the first table.